# Uploaded file is not saved in folder

Tags: php, html

I have created one form in which one file field is there where the file is uploaded and saved in a folder named "att".
code is as:

```
if($_FILES['file'] != '') 
 {
    //Settings 

    $allowed_extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp", "pdf", "docx","xlsx");
    echo $upload_folder = './att/'; //<-- this folder must be writeable by the script


    $errors ='';

    //Get the uploaded file information
    echo $name_of_uploaded_file = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

    //get the file extension of the file
    $type_of_uploaded_file = substr($name_of_uploaded_file, 
                            strrpos($name_of_uploaded_file, '.') + 1);

    $size_of_uploaded_file = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
```

This code is run but the file is not show in folder. What is the problem in code

Answer (score 5):

Please add **move_uploaded_file()** on the code.

Something like these:

```
<?php
if($_FILES['file'] != '') 
 {
    //Settings 

    $allowed_extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp", "pdf", "docx","xlsx");
    $upload_folder = './att/'; //<-- this folder must be writeable by the script


    $errors ='';

    //Get the uploaded file information
    $name_of_uploaded_file = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

    //get the file extension of the file
    $type_of_uploaded_file = substr($name_of_uploaded_file, 
                            strrpos($name_of_uploaded_file, '.') + 1);

     $size_of_uploaded_file = $_FILES["file"]["size"];

     move_uploaded_file($name_of_uploaded_file, $upload_folder);     
  }

?>
```

Make sure the folder **att** is rewritable.

Answer (score 5):

You are just using file details not moving it. For moving you sholud use `move_uploaded_file`\

```
eg: 

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "PLACE WHERE YOU WANT TO MOVE")
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `move_uploaded_file` function. Refer to this example: [move_uploaded_file](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)